# how to set attribute of html form from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i want to change the attribute of a text element from required to not required. I am using javascript to do this. i am calling a function based on the input of the radio button and i am using html 5..

Comment: post example to jsFiddle please!

Comment: @MihaiIorga i was validation the form elements before clicking submit button. bcoz there was a property in the html5 called required.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("adiv").removeAttribute("style")

document.getElementById("myimage").setAttribute("src","another.gif")

var getvalue=document.getElementById("myimage").getAttribute("src")
```

Now but it in a function and use it how you wish.

That is how you get set and remove attributes in JavaScript.

Source: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml

Comment: i tried this code
document.getElementsByName("twelthPercentage").setAttribute("required");
but i didn't work can u tell me why

Comment: document.getElementsByName("twelthPercentage").setAttribute("required","true") maybe? please create a JS fiddle with issues or read teh documentation

Comment: @Sivashankar, you probably need to use getElementById not getElementsByName. If problems continue, please post sufficient part of the code.